# Python & Json - Ebay Api Upload image Error

Tags: python, json, api

I've been trying to upload a png image to the Ebay Api with the return_file_upload call:
http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/post-order/post-order_v2_return-returnId_file_upload__post.html#Samples

It's weird because the documentation says it accepts an array for the data parameter but the samples doesn't use arrays. When I tried using an array I got a `Can not deserialize instance of byte out of VALUE_STRING at [Source: java.io.SequenceInputStream@4d57f134; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.ebay.marketplace.returns.v3.services.request.UploadFileRequest["data"])`

This is my code:

```
import json
import base64
import requests

with open("take_full_login.png", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.encodestring(image_file.read())
url2 = 'https://api.ebay.com/post-order/v2/return/123456/file/upload'
payload2 = {
  "data" : encoded_string,
  "filePurpose" : "LABEL_RELATED"
}
requests.post(url=url2, data=json.dumps(payload2), headers=headers)
```

That currently outputs
`{"error":[{"errorId":1616,"domain":"returnErrorDomain","severity":"ERROR","category":"REQUEST","message":"Invalid Input.","parameter":[{"value":"data","name":"parameter"}],"longMessage":"Invalid Input.","httpStatusCode":400}]}`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `data=json.dumps(payload2)` by `json=payload2`

The call /post-order/v2/cancellation/check_eligibility only worked that way for me